# M2.2.4 - Category page listing all products (when products per page set to 24)

Tags: magento2, category-products, magento2.2.4, category-listing

I am experiencing an odd and troubling problem.

On our production environment, all product pages are listing all products on the single page, in which some pages will have north of 2-300 products, which obviously causes incredible load times for the page and the like (even with lazy loading on the images and such).

The peculiar part is with the exact same settings and environment placed on our staging server, it works as expected, and has the paging with only 24 products per page. That is where I am lost as to why/how this is happening.

I have tried all the common methods of having this corrected:

```
Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront
---> Setting `Products per Page on Grid Default Value`
     to the desired value (which is a value given in
     `Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values`

---> Allow All Products per Page set to `No`
```

I also have tried using XML updates within the categories design themselves, using:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
      <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
             <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">24</argument>
      </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Again, all these changes and testing them with other numbers work on the staging environment but alas on the production, it continues to always stay displaying all products on a single page.

I assume somehow, somewhere be it with messing with different extensions or what, something got hardcoded somewhere or something, but I am at a loss.

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you get a solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by finding out an extension that was affecting it for whatever reason (Tatvic_EnhancedEcommerce was the one for me) -- I had an outdated version, once I updated it was working as intended.